# Unable to connect SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: php, sql-server

i have one page for register ... all my config is right but my register.php can't connect to my sql server..

Error

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: x.x.x.x in C:\xampp\htdocs\rfweb\regis.php on line 81
```

code in line 81 is

```
$connectsql=mssql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die('<center><b>'.$lang_error_cant_connect1.'</b><br>'.$lang_error_cant_connect2.'<br><br><a href="regis.php">Back</a></center>');
```

spesification : 
SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and xampp 1.6

i've try to setting ODBC, Restart SQL, ect

anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try sqlsrv queries instead of mssql, and make sure you properly configured the ports of your xampp. Another thing, try to check whether you have IIS, maybe it's blocking your xampp.

Comment: My XAMPP running with no error ... as evidence of my webserver can already online but to the only error in register ...

Comment: Double check your script or change your queries to sqlsrv because I've also tried to connect to ms sql using sqlsrv queries.